# IK Chain Confusion: Unable to affect hand's rotation without affecting whole chain

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics, bone.constraints

I've built about a dozen IK chains before. I must be going senile over here.

When I *rotate the hand control* in what I believe is a standard IK setup, *the entire arm rotates*. I am unable to affect only the hand while working with the IK chain. The IK chain also feels like it moves differently, generally, than I'm used to...

Any explanation about what I'm missing would be cherished.

Cheers!

[image]

[image: Example]

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard IK setup."  We need to know what the bones are doing, and the best way to show us that is to provide a file.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I've added the blend file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IK Constraint setting, disable the Weight Rotation option:

[image]

Then, in Edit mode, make sure the IK chain is bent in the direction you want it to fold so that the IK can work:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, Lock. I'd been toggling Weight Rotation on/off while troubleshooting. 

Bending the IK chain (after confirming Weight Rotation was toggled back off) restored expected functionality. 

What a simple concept! Very good to know.